# Question about time format in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I heared from someone that you can adjust one of SQL server settings in order to make deal with (time) datatype as a 12-hour system instead of 24-hour system ??

is that true ?

if is it , then how can I do it ?? cuz I need it badly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL stores it date format in the same way regardless of local date time formats

Have a look at this link on using the convert function for date and time if you just need to display in a particular format http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1145

Comment: Exactly - TIME is a TIME is a TIME - it doesn't have any formatting associated with it, and since the day has 24 hours, the TIME stores 24 hours (obviuosly!). The differences only come out when converting to VARCHAR for display...